# Missing values while returning Object in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

This is my ASP.NET CORE WEB API Method

```
     [HttpGet]
     [Route("schooltypegroups")]
     [Produces("application/json")]
     [SwaggerOperation("GetSchoolTypeGroups")]
     [SwaggerResponse(400, "Bad input parameter")]
     [SwaggerResponse(404, "Not found")]
     [SwaggerResponse(500, "Internal server error")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> GetSchoolTypeGroups()
     {
        try
        {
           var devicetypegroups = await _context.SchoolTypeGroups
                .Include(b => b.SchoolTypes)
                .Include(p => p.Students)
                 .ThenInclude(student=> student.StudentGroup)
                  .ToListAsync(); 
              //Now, studenttypegroups is having all proper data

              return Ok(studenttypegroups);   

              //But returned Null child entities
              //Student and StudentGroup is empty in json response like this [] 
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {                
            return new ServerErrorResult();
        }
     }
```

I see all the proper values inside `studenttypegroups` while debugging.

But, returned JSON has null values for child entities.!!

Anything I am missing?

**My Guess**

I was using `ResponseType` attribute in .net framework. But I do not see it in asp.net code

Json Output shows `Students` empty

[image]

I think it's lazy loading issue, which is not implemented in .net core https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3797

Comment: does your classes have recursion?

Comment: can you include json data in your question?

Comment: updated json in question. Yes class have child to child relations

Comment: not the final json. please add actual one

Comment: what u mean by actual one. Data comes from DB

Comment: Is this same as what you see in DB? is Students empty in DB?

Comment: every data is available and reached and assigned to `studenttypegroups. it only fails while returning . please see comments in my question

Comment: ok what is the above screenshot? is it returning data? or debug data? I need debug data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186262/discussion-between-simonare-and-kudlatiger).

Comment: This may be a reference loop issue, although that should have blocked all serialization.